# Subtract an RDD from another RDD doesn't work correctly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to subtract an RDD from another RDD. I looked into the documentation and I found that `subtract` can do that. Actually, when I tested `subtract`, the final RDD remains the same and the values are not removed!

Is there any other function to do that? Or am I using `subtract` incorrectly?

Here is the code that I used:

```
 val vertexRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(VertexId, Array[Int])]
 val clusters  = vertexRDD.takeSample(false, 3)
 val clustersRDD: RDD[(VertexId, Array[Int])] = sc.parallelize(clusters)
 val final = vertexRDD.subtract(clustersRDD)
 final.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing set operations like subtract with mutable types (Array in this example) is usually unsupported, or at least not recommended.

Try using a immutable type instead.

I believe [WrappedArray](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray) is the relevant container for storing arrays in sets, but i'm not sure.

Comment: I need to use an Array ! How can I fix that ? Or what is the other type that I can use ? Otherwise, I think that Array is an immutable type in Scala.

Comment: @OmarMasmoudi No, `Array` is just the same mutable JVM array as in other languages. The only difference is, it is handled not covariantly in Scala (it is invariant in Scala).

Comment: @OphirYoktan Ah okay ! Thank you ! It works when I tested with Seq !

Answer (score 2):

If your rdd is composed of mutables object it wont work... problem is it wont show an error either so this kind of problems are hard to identify, i had a similar one yesterday and i used a workaround.

```
rdd.keyBy( someImmutableValue ) -> do this using the same key value to
 both your rdds

val resultRDD = rdd.subtractByKey(otherRDD).values
```

Answer (score 1):

> Recently I tried the subtract operation of 2 RDDs (of array List) and it is working. The important note is - the RDD val after .subtract method should be the list from where you're subtracting, not the other way around.

Correct: `val result = theElementYouWantToSubtract.subtract(fromList)`

Incorrrect: `val reuslt = fromList.subtract(theElementYouWantToSubtract)` (will not give any compile/runtime error message)