# Computing the set difference of two RDDs of Array[Int]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDDs, say A and B, of the type `RDD[Array[Int]]` and want to compute the set difference A - B and B - A. I tried the following code

```
val R1 = A.subtract(B)
val R2 = B.subtract(A)
```

but it does not return the correct answer. In a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830382/subtract-an-rdd-from-another-rdd-doesnt-work-correctly), it is mentioned that "*Performing set operations like subtract with mutable types (Array in this example) is usually unsupported, or at least not recommended*." So I have to change the code to

```
val A1 = A.map(_.to[ArrayBuffer]).persist()
val B1 = B.map(_.to[ArrayBuffer]).persist()
val R1 = A1.subtract(B1)
val R2 = B1.subtract(A1)
```

Now it returns the correct answer. I want to know **if there is any more efficient way to do this**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer is misleading. The problem is not mutability. `Arraybuffer` which solved the problem is mutable as well.

`subtract` internally compares elements using `equals` and `equals` method of java arrays is broken (it just defaults to reference equality).

`A1.map(_.toSeq).subtract(A2.map(_.toSeq))` will work.

`.toSeq` wraps java arrays into scala's `WrappedArray` which has less surprising implementation of equality.